# Ampersand seems to be splitting my variable - batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following code which works beautifully

```
set "findest=\\CFFS\CF_Networked_Files\!!CLIENT DOCUMENTS\%PrimaryApplicantLast%, %PrimaryApplicantlFirst%"
.....
@echo %DATE% %time:~0,-6% [%findest%] >> log.txt
```

When I run the same commands, but with the %findest% being slightly longer and containing an & symbol, it seems to split the %findest% variable at, or just after the &.

Problem code -

```
SET "findest=\\CFFS\CF_Networked_Files\!!CLIENT DOCUMENTS\%PrimaryApplicantLast%, %PrimaryApplicantlFirst% & %SecondaryApplicantLast%, %SecondaryApplicantFirst%"
....
@echo %DATE% %time:~0,-6% [%findest%] >> log.txt
```

There is plenty more going on in my code, but it is the writing to my log file that throws up an error, the error being the %SecondaryApplicantLast% isn't a valid command, leaving me to believe that my code has been split.

Error -

```
Press any key to continue . . .
Wed 24/02/2016 13:21 [\\CFFS\CF_Networked_Files\!!CLIENT DOCUMENTS\EXAMPLE, test

'EXAMPLE2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Cheers

EDIT -

```
@echo
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo.


echo. Client Folder Creator! 
echo.
echo. Follow the instructions to create appropriate client folders. 
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:choice
Set /P c=".Are there multiple applicants[Y/N]?"


:Primary
echo.
echo "Primary Applicant" 
echo.
set /P "PrimaryApplicantlFirst=Enter First Name: "
set /P "PrimaryApplicantLast=Enter Last Name: "
echo.

call :toUpper PrimaryApplicantLast


if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :CreateFolders
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :Secondary


:Secondary
echo "Secondary Applicant" 
echo.
set /P "SecondaryApplicantFirst=Enter First Name: "
set /P "SecondaryApplicantLast=Enter Last Name: "
echo.

call :toUpper SecondaryApplicantLast


goto :CreateFoldersMulti


:CreateFoldersMulti
SET "findest=\\CFFS\CF_Networked_Files\!!CLIENT DOCUMENTS\%PrimaryApplicantLast%, %PrimaryApplicantlFirst% ^& %SecondaryApplicantLast%, %SecondaryApplicantFirst%"
robocopy Z:\ProjectIT\BAT\test "%findest%" /e /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS
SET blanknum=1
SET "finsubdest=-BLANK-%PrimaryApplicantLast% & %SecondaryApplicantLast%."

IF EXIST "%findest%\%blanknum%%finsubdest%" ( 
    SET /A blanknum=blanknum+1     
) 
IF EXIST "%findest%\%blanknum%%finsubdest%" ( 
    SET /A blanknum=blanknum+1     
) 
IF EXIST "%findest%\%blanknum%%finsubdest%" ( 
    SET /A blanknum=blanknum+1     
) 
IF EXIST "%findest%\%blanknum%%finsubdest%" ( 
    SET /A blanknum=blanknum+1     
) 

robocopy Z:\ProjectIT\BAT\Construction "%findest%\%blanknum%%finsubdest%" /e /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS


echo Folder has been created for "%PrimaryApplicantLast% & %SecondaryApplicantLast%"
echo.
@echo "%findest%"
echo.


pause


@echo %DATE% %time:~0,-6% [%findest%] >> log.txt


%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "%findest%"

pause

goto :eof


:CreateFolders
set "source=Z:\ProjectIT\BAT\test"
set "findest=\\CFFS\CF_Networked_Files\!!CLIENT DOCUMENTS\%PrimaryApplicantLast%, %PrimaryApplicantlFirst%"
robocopy "%source%" "%findest%" /e /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS
SET blanknum=1
set finsubdest=-BLANK-%PrimaryApplicantLast%

IF EXIST "%findest%\%blanknum%%finsubdest%" ( 
    SET /A blanknum=blanknum+1     
) 
IF EXIST "%findest%\%blanknum%%finsubdest%" ( 
    SET /A blanknum=blanknum+1     
) 
IF EXIST "%findest%\%blanknum%%finsubdest%" ( 
    SET /A blanknum=blanknum+1     
) 
IF EXIST "%findest%\%blanknum%%finsubdest%" ( 
    SET /A blanknum=blanknum+1     
) 

robocopy Z:\ProjectIT\BAT\Construction "%findest%\%blanknum%%finsubdest%" /e /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS


echo Folder has been created for "%PrimaryApplicantLast%"
echo.
echo %findest%
echo.


pause


@echo %DATE% %time:~0,-6% [%findest%] >> log.txt



%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "%findest%"

goto :eof
:---------------------------------------------------------------------


:toUpper str -- converts lowercase character to uppercase
if not defined %~1 EXIT /b
for %%a in ("a=A" "b=B" "c=C" "d=D" "e=E" "f=F" "g=G" "h=H" "i=I"
            "j=J" "k=K" "l=L" "m=M" "n=N" "o=O" "p=P" "q=Q" "r=R"
            "s=S" "t=T" "u=U" "v=V" "w=W" "x=X" "y=Y" "z=Z" "ä=Ä"
            "ö=Ö" "ü=Ü") do (
    call set %~1=%%%~1:%%~a%%
)
EXIT /b
```

Answer (score 1):

Precede the <kbd>&</kbd> with a caret <kbd>^</kbd> thus: `^&`

The caret will, if used judiciously, turn off the special meaning of the following character (<kbd>&</kbd> is "concatenate commands")

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "PrimaryApplicantLast=PAL"
:: Examine the next SET very carefully. It's copied directly from your original code...
SET "PrimaryApplicantlFirst=PAF"
SET "SecondaryApplicantLast=SAL"
SET "SecondaryApplicantFirst=SAF"
SET "findest=\\CFFS\CF_Networked_Files\!!CLIENT DOCUMENTS\%PrimaryApplicantLast%, %PrimaryApplicantlFirst% ^& %SecondaryApplicantLast%, %SecondaryApplicantFirst%"
SET fi
@echo %DATE% %time:~0,-6% [%findest%]

GOTO :EOF
```

For me yields:

```
findest=\\CFFS\CF_Networked_Files\!!CLIENT DOCUMENTS\PAL, PAF ^& SAL, SAF
24/02/2016 13:45 [\\CFFS\CF_Networked_Files\!!CLIENT DOCUMENTS\PAL, PAF & SAL, SAF]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this produced the same error. I will post my whole code - maybe the error lies elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe if you repeated the operation in the setting of `finsubdest` ?

Comment: no dice with that either. My code is causing other weird errors. It is dropping the !! from !!CLIENT DOCUMENTS and copying the files into a new folder CLIENT DOCUMENTS. Bad day for batch maybe. I'll have another look tomorrow!

Comment: Disappearing `!` implies that you are running with `delayedexpansion`. You can disable this with `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion`.

Comment: this was the case, thank you! Still no fix for the & issue though.

Comment: Through a combination of your ^& and reformatting, I have made some progress but there is still an issue. It is now correctly writing to the log file, however the file produced is showing ^& in the name, not just &. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Where using a variable which includes `^&` and the `^` is being used literally (eg `echo` will use `^` as an escape, but `>%filename%` will use it literally, and `^` will appear in the filename) use `>"%filename:^=%"` to remove all `^`or `"%filename:^&=&%"` to convert all `^&` to `&`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104371/discussion-between-joshua-patterson-and-magoo).

Comment: Can you replace "&" with "and" ?

Comment: I worked around this by recreating the variable to be printed but using ^& and just using & in the original. Thanks for the ^& tip!